# How to bind to form with variable number of input fields?

Tags: forms, angular, binding

I have a form that asks members for topics. if you start entering a function will look up previous topics in order to add suggestions by binding the input to querytopic. if somebody wants he can add more topics. However the new input field will bind to the same query as the previous input. So all the inputfields will get the same value. Is there way to overcome this problem.

```
<div formArrayName="topics" class="form horizontal">
      <div *ngFor="let topic of topics.controls; let i=index [formGroupName]="i">
          <div class="form-group">
              <input type ="hidden" class="form-control" formControlName="id" value={{i}}>
          </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="topic" class="col-lg-2 mr-2">Topic {{i+1}}:</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                  <input [(ngModel)]=querytopic (keyup)=filtertopic($event) (blur)=handleBlur() class="form-control form-control-sm" formControlName="topic" id="topic">
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addTopic()" >+</button>
                  </span>
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="removeTopic(i)" type="button">x</button>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div><!--Questions bij de recomendation-->
      </div>
```

the function that adds a topic:

```
 addTopic () {
    this.topics.push(this.fb.group(new Topic()));
  }
```

query function looks up in the list of Topics matching values:

```
filtertopic(event: any) {
    if (this.querytopic !== "") {
      this.onderdeel = "topic";
        this.filteredList = this.Topics.filter(function (el) {
            return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.querytopic.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        }.bind(this));
    } else {
        this.filteredList = [];
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably the problem is with `[(ngModel)]`... Since you're using it inside `*ngFor`, every input will reference the same variable `queryTopic`. To solve this, you should change queryTopic (maybe rename It to `queryTopics`) to array and reference it in `ngModel` passing the Index (`queryTopics[i]`). Now the question is: for what are you using this? I'd suggest you to use only `formControlName` and it'll automatically bind the values from component.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but not really making progress. how would i get different formControlNames in the array and how could i acces them in the component file?

Comment: Simply doing this in template `(keyup)="filtertopic(i)"` and in component: `filtertopic(idx: number) { const currentCtrl = this.topics.get(\`${idx}.topic\`); ... }`?